# Resultados en blanco en una consulta con rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Realicé una función que le da formato a un rango de fechas para que puedan ser utilizadas para una consulta en MySQL.

Al imprimir `$a` y `$b` las tengo así, eso me llevó a pensar que todo está correcto, pero no. MySQL no me hace la consulta:

```
a)       2021-01-21 06:00:00
b)       2021-01-22 06:00:00
```

El código PHP es:

```
function FAC0014($a, $b){

    
    echo $a; echo $b; 
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT Id_user, Id_state FROM binplaza_colas.quotes WHERE Time_registry BETWEEN :in AND :to'); 
    $query->execute([
        'in'           => $a,
        'to'           => $b
        ]);
    return $query;
}
```

Debo mencionar que el tipo de dato de `Time_registry` es `datatime` y que realizando la consulta en el MDB sí me lanza los resultados.

**editado**

Ejecutando:

```
$query->debugDumpParams()
```

Obtuve esto:

```
2021-01-22 06:00:002021-01-23 06:00:00SQL: [91] SELECT Id_user, Id_state FROM binplaza_colas.quotes WHERE Time_registry BETWEEN :in AND :to
Sent SQL: [127] SELECT Id_user, Id_state FROM binplaza_colas.quotes WHERE Time_registry BETWEEN '2021-01-22 06:00:00' AND '2021-01-23 06:00:00'
Params:  2
Key: Name: [3] :in
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":in"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [3] :to
paramno=-1
name=[3] ":to"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

Y la función que itera esto dice que es nulo:

> [22-Jan-2021 11:34:05 Europe/Madrid] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on null in ....

Y la función:

```
function FAF0011($a){
    $mys = new Mys();
//  error_log(print_r($a.'<br>'.$b,true)); //depurrador php
    $a = date ('Y-m-d 06:00:00' , strtotime($a));
    $b = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime('+24 hour', strtotime($a)));
    $res = $mys->FAC0014($a, $b);
    if ($res->rowCount() >= 1) {
        $row = $res->fetch();
        $items = array(
            'a_a'       => $row['Id_user'],
            'a_b'       => $row['Id_state']
        );
    } else {
    /* En caso de ir mal mostramos el mensaje de error */
    die(
        htmlspecialchars(
            implode(", ", $res->errorInfo())
        )
    );

    $this->FAF0002($items,1);
}
```

**Reeditado**

Ésta es una prueba de que me falta mucho por aprender. Con suerte el error te ayuda y ésta fue la solución:

```
  while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
        /* Agregamos un nuevo elemento */
        array_push($items, array(
            'a_a'       => $row['Id_user'],
            'a_b'       => $row['Id_state']
        ));
    }
```

Obvié el método correcto de cómo usar los resultados de MySQL:

```
   ->rowCount()
```

Se estaba usando mal. Gracias a [@OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) por la solución.

Comment: en tu `return` has esto `return return $query->debugDumpParams();` y comentanos que resultado obtienes

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on null in .., tengo un contador que verifica si hay filas, y muestra ese error

Comment: No, antes del contador, prueba directamente la pura consulta que expones para que podamos ver si se le estan o no pasando los valores de las variables

Comment: sigo sorprendido colgue la respuesta editando la pregunta, probe una vez mas la consulta directamente en el gestor y si funciona.

Comment: Pues el debug nos indica que las cosas marchan bien, los valores si llegan, ¿seguro que si tienes programado el recorrido e impresión de los valores?

Comment: si master, colgue la funcion para para echarle un vistaso.

Comment: Me parece que te estás olvidando los dos puntos que hay poner delante el nombre de cada marcador. ¿Podrías probar lo siguiente? `$query->execute([':in' => $a, ':to'  => $b]);`. Al no comprobar el resultado de `$query->execute()` estás pasando por alto que algo está fallando.

Comment: sigue emitiendo error, tengo otras consultas que están sin los dos punticos y corren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo dos cambios para evitar problemas en tu código:

Es importante poner dos puntos delante del nombre de cada marcador. Además, al no comprobar el resultado de `$query->execute()` estás pasando por alto un fallo en la consulta SQL.

Te recomiendo hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
function FAC0014($a, $b){
    // echo $a; echo $b;
    $conexion = $this->connect();
    $query = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT Id_user, Id_state
        FROM binplaza_colas.quotes
        WHERE Time_registry BETWEEN :in AND :to
    '); 
    /* Si la preparación no es emulada, comprobamos si fue bien */
    if ($query === false) {
        /* En caso de ir mal mostramos el mensaje de error */
        die(
            htmlspecialchars(
                implode(", ", $conexion->errorInfo())
            )
        );
    }
    $resultado = $query->execute([
        ':in' => $a,
        ':to' => $b,
    ]);
    /* Comprobamos si la consulta SQL fue bien */
    if ($resultado === false) {
        /* En caso de ir mal mostramos el mensaje de error */
        die(
            htmlspecialchars(
                implode(", ", $query->errorInfo())
            )
        );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Además, estás usando [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](https://php.net/es/pdostatement.rowcount) de manera incorrecta:

> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última sentencia `DELETE`, `INSERT`, o `UPDATE` ejecutada por el correspondiente objeto `PDOStatement`.

> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto `PDOStatement` asociado fue una sentencia `SELECT`, algunas bases de datos podrían devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. **Sin embargo, este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.**

Además, estás obteniendo únicamente un registro. Para obtenerlos todos debes realizar un bucle que los almacene todos en la variable deseada (`$item`).

Aquí está el código que te propongo:

```
function FAF0011($a) {
    $mys = new Mys();
    $a = date ('Y-m-d 06:00:00' , strtotime($a));
    $b = date ('Y-m-d H:i:s' , strtotime('+24 hour', strtotime($a)));
    $res = $mys->FAC0014($a, $b);
    /* Agregamos los registros obtenidos a $items */
    $items = array();
    while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
        /* Agregamos un nuevo elemento */
        array_push($items, array(
            'a_a'       => $row['Id_user'],
            'a_b'       => $row['Id_state']
        ));
    }
    $this->FAF0002($items,1);
}
```

Edición: Pruebas realizadas en:

- Repositorio GIT: https://github.com/ojgarciab/422659-stackoverflow-es
- Prueba en línea con Gitpod: gitpod.io#https://github.com/ojgarciab/422659-stackoverflow-es

Comment: Bueno, puse lo dos puntos  pero sigue emitiendo error, además que todas mis consultas no las traen y funcionan perfectamente esta me ha salido como la oveja negra.

Comment: Puede ser un error en el `prepare` o en el `execute`. ¿Has probado un `var_export($query)` justo tras el `connect()->prepare()`?

Comment: var_export($query);
   $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT Id_user, Id_state FROM binplaza_colas.quotes WHERE Time_registry BETWEEN :in AND :to');
lo acabo de intentar y esta igual

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta para gestionar una mala preparación de la consulta SQL. He tenido que separar la conexión en una variable para poder extraer de ella el mensaje de error.

Comment: En cuanto a tu último comentario, no, me refería al `var_export` **después** de la preparación. Todo apunta a que no se está realizando correctamente. Además, tratas de hacer `rowCount()` sobre una consulta que no ha actualizado registros, por lo que puede que no te funcione como esperas (ojo, algunas veces sí, otras veces no, depende del SGBD y el controlador MySQL).

Comment: Existen varias incongruencias con lo que pones en la pregunta. Por lo pronto el error de `null` al hacer `rowCount()` implicaría que `$query` vale `null`, cuando lo normal es que `$query` valga `false` cuando falla la preparación. ¿Has probado a comprobar si `$resultado` llega a valer `$false`?

Comment: Has puesto el código en mal lugar. Estás comprobando las cosas en la función `FAF0011()` y eso está mal porque en ella la variable `$query` no existe. Mis modificaciones te indiqué que las hicieras en `FAC0014()`.

Comment: si, si me di cuenta ya lo corregi, y pense que era eso pero sigue saliendo error

Comment: Aún así has cambiado la lógica de la comprobación. [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118780/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-xavruss).